# Correctly Navigating to React Route from Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to navigate to a react route after making a post request using the data returned from the post request. What's the correct way to do it using the latest react router?

```
import {Router} from react-router 

.....
.....

fetch(post_request).then(function(response){
    return response.json()
}).then(function(response){
    this.props.router.push('/new/information/' + response)
})
```

However this gives me an error saying router is not defined. How can I correctly navigate in react router in this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to call router from `context`

```
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
  fetch(post_request).then(function(response){
      return response.json()
  }).then(function(response){
      this.context.router.push('/new/information/' + response)
  })
```

Comment: this gives me an error context is undefined. how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Which version of react-router you use  and if you use version >2.0.0 then did you define the contextTypes in your component

Comment: Hi, the code is working now with some small modifications however the browser URL is not changing. I'm using the latest version of react, new question here please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973549/react-router-push-url-not-changing