# React Router Push URL not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router for my project, and I want to navigate to a route after post request, the code works fine and navigates to the route but the URL of the browser is not changing, here is the code

```
 import { Route, browserHistroy} from 'react-router'
 ..........
 ..........
 var state = this
 fetch(post_request).then(function(response){
    return response.json()
 }).then(function(response){
    state.context.router.push({pathname: 'new/info/' + response.user})
 })

 ....
 Component.contextTypes = {
     router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
 };
```

However although the code works and the route is being loaded the URL of the browser is not changing. How can I fix this and what am I doing wrong? Thanks

**Routes**

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <Route path="new/user" component={NewUser}></Route>
      <Route path="new/info/:pid" component={NewUserInfo}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Comment: How have you defined your routes . Can you post that snippet too.

Comment: ok I added the routes, the transition is happening from ```/new/user``` to ```new/info/:pid```